# Returning a javascript object with return {} is actually being confused with destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, babeljs

I have a function called `readMessage` in React Native that does the following return:

```
readMessage = async function(id) {
    ...
    return {
        id         : id,
        sender     : sender,
        subject    : subject,
        message    : message,
        attachments: attachments,
        sentDate   : sentDate
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
            queue = [];

            for (emptyMessage of emptyMessages) {
                m = this.readMessage(emptyMessage.sisgradId);
                queue.push(m);
            }

            for (message of queue) {
                await message;
                console.log(message.message);
                console.log(message.id);
                console.log(message);
            }
```

As you can see, I'm using a `queue` so I can push `x` promises at a time, then wait for all `x` with await until I can go again.

There are 2 very strange things happening here. In the logs, I see 2 `undefined`s and then the message. That is, `message.message` and `message.id` are `undefined` and `message` is simply a string with the message. That's why I think it has to do with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Now, if I change `message` to `m`, like this:

```
        for (m of queue) {
            await m;
            console.log(m.message);
            console.log(m.id);
            console.log(m);
        }
```

then I see 2 `undefined`s and then a `Promise`. Why wouldn't `await m` wait for the `Promise` resolution?

My `.babelrc` is  `"presets": ["react-native"]` and I'm using

```
 "react-native": "0.54.2",
```

Comment: `await message;`  your waiting, that's great.. but your not doing anything with the return value..  `const msg = await message; console.log(msg.message)`  etc.

Comment: you use the word `destructuring` in the title ... where are you destructuring? note: `m` in `m of queue` is a **Promise** ... promises have no message or id property, hence the `undefined` - `await m` **does** wait for the promise, and **returns** the resolved value - which you effectively throw away

Comment: @Keith you're rigth, it works, totally misunderstood how await works